# Is screen burn-in a problem?

Tags: glass-cockpit, display

Screen burn-in can be a problem for older and cheaper monitors.  It can be caused by fixed-width text, fixed-size graphics, and operating for long durations, which are things that are common in aircraft displays.

So is burn-in a problem for aircraft? Have there been hardware or software improvements to minimize burn-in?

Comment: Personally I've never seen a screen burnt on a modern monitor (e.g. post 1985), and "protections" like screen savers have never been required for CRT. Old CRT, with old phosphor (e.g. on [oscilloscopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscilloscope) at slow scan speed) were problematic. Tube manufacturers were only a handful, and all competing for the best quality.

Comment: @mins, I've seen plenty of burnt-in later-generation (1990s) CRT computer monitors. Generally it was noticeable only on a switched off screen, but then rather clearly. I've also seen a badly burnt-in LCD monitor, but that one was on for weeks if not months, displaying the same white-on-black text.

Comment: Burn in is a problem with current OLED displays, which are primarily used in phones

Comment: @Zeus not seen any burnt in screens in a long time though, last probably was in the early 2000s working in a software testing lab where the same screens were often on for weeks or months on end showing the same information, mimicking the production environment those systems would be used in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was in the Regional Jet industry a long time and never heard of screen burn-in as a complaint on Rockwell Collins ProLine CRTs.  You mentioned "cheaper" monitors and that may be the key.  CRTs built to an aviation TSO (Technical Standards Order) are by no means cheap.

Comment: One would also hope that the screens are easily replaceable, too.